# Phonegap LocalStorage - are filesystem permissions required

Tags: android, cordova, file-permissions

Am making a basic phonegap based android app.  All working perfectly and using localstorage (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage) to save data.

I am using

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

in my config.xml .  When I install the package it still asks for internet, network and storage.. which is ok and I understand when I upload this to the market it will actually only require Internet (great).

My question is ;)  **Do I need the filesystem permissions  to use localstorage?**  Or by virtue of using having Internet Permissions does it get access to the DomLocalStorage? I just don't want to require any more permissions than completely necessary.

I will be trying this myself anyway and post the answer if no one replies.. but I figured it might help someone else out anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect not. PhoneGap uses the same localstorage as the browser, which does not require special permissions to be set. So I can't imagine that you would need to explicitly set filesystem permission in your manifest.

Comment: how did you fix this? I am having the xame issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem even now, using Cordova. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions infiltrated somehow into AndroidManifest.xml.

LocalStorage does not *necessarily* create these permissions, only *sometimes*. I didn't figure out when, but I got them always when using *createjs* framework. (Not sure whether it's a sort of causality.)

There seem to be more irregularities... In one project, I managed to get rid of these permissions just by deleting them from AndroidManifest. In another, this did not help, and they were renewed after each build. The only thing that "helped" was to remove localStorage from the JS code altogether AND reinstall the android platform in the project.